# Why should I use an additional layout file to present a ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am new in android technology and learning via net tutorials. While binding List View i am in a confusion that why we create a separate layout file and call that layout file in arrayadapter

Comment: You do that when you want to create a custom `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source for the code shown below: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

When you are creating a simple `ListView`, you will use something like this:

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        "Linux", "OS/2" };

// Define a new Adapter
// First parameter - Context
// Second parameter - Layout for the row
// Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
// Forth - the Array of data

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);


// Assign adapter to ListView
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When creating a custom `ListView`, you will typically do something like this:

```
package de.vogella.android.listactivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        textView.setText(values[position]);
        // Change the icon for Windows and iPhone
        String s = values[position];
        if (s.startsWith("iPhone")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

In this example, if you look at the line: 
`View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);`, the `R.layout.rowlayout` is your custom layout used to show your custom `ListView`.

Refer to the source link at the top of the answer for a detailed tutorial on `ListView's`.

Comment: @Cupcake: Nope. It didn't come from there. The source of the code is already attributed right in the first sentence of this answer. Your second part is correct. This is part of a tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

separate xml is created for every row of listview. listview needs items to display, so that should be displayed using some view like textview,imageview......So depending upon the need you need that layout.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create a separate layout. You can create layouts on run time.