# Why does ListView need its container item in a sperate layout file

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

My questions stems from doing the tutorials for Android development, namely the Sunshine application. The specific code is [here](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2/pull/1/files#diff-4787e6090d7a34f046f62575488c5cff) (a github pull request diff).

I have a ListView inside a FrameLayout in one layout XML file. Now, to use the ListView with an ViewAdapter (ArrayAdapter in my case) I need to have a layout specification for the container the adapter and ListView will utilize (a TextView in my case). Why does that container need to be in a separate layout file? (as presented in the github link)
I have attempted putting the TextView in the same layout file and changing the code appropriately, but it just crashes (I was not able to debug it successfully):
XML:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView_forecast"
    />

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_forecast_textview"
    />
```

The relevant Java code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            // create some fake data
            String[] arrayList = {
                    "Today - Sunny - 35/30",
                    "Tomorrow - Very Sunny - 45/43",
                    "Today - Dangerous - 55/54",
                    "Today - Deadly - 62/60",
                    "Today - Boild an egg? - 100/93",
                    "Today - Radioactive fallout - 135/130",
                    "Today - Sunny side up - 150/130",
                    "Today - Burn - 4000/3978",
            };
            // pump it into something more managable
            ArrayList<String> weatherList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arrayList));

            // now create an adapter for the list view so it can feed them to the screen
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                    new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getActivity(),
                            R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,
                    weatherList);

            // get the list view from the current activity
            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_forecast);

            // finally set the adapter
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            return rootView;
        }
```

The question appeared in an unclear form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378150/why-should-i-use-an-additional-layout-file-to-present-a-listview) - I hope I have rephrased it correctly.

Comment: Because you are dynamically inflating/recycling views for your adapter. The view's aren't statically added to the main layout, they are too dynamic for that. Think about it like this, your layout is your home's blueprint, your fragment is the house that gets built from the plans, and the adapter for the ListView is like the garage. You can change the cars in the garage, you can have a different number of cars in the garage, you can take a car out, paint it, and put it back in the garage, but at no point would you ever want the car to be part of the blueprints. It just doesn't make sense there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextView` in your layout is not a child of the `ListView`, it is a sibling. `ListView` manages its children based on how many items your adapter reports, how large each child (row) is, and how much space there is on screen to show them.

Regardless of whatever view you use for the row, each row needs its own *instance* of that view. Placing a view inside of a layout will cause *one* instance to be created and added to the view hierarchy, but `ListView` can have an arbitrary number of children depending on the data in your adapter. If your adapter has 3 items and each row is simply a `TextView`, then you need 3 `TexView`s to display them all, not just the one you added.

That's why it doesn't make sense to include the row layout anywhere in the same layout as the `ListView`.

Comment: Go it. So the external layout with the ListView item is just a blueprint layout for each item the ListView will generate? Hence it needs to be standalone?

Comment: @LeviU Basically yes (I assume you mean the external layout with the `TextView` item, not the `ListView` item). Technically you don't need that blueprint layout, you can generate the views purely in java code inside of `getView()`, but each row still has its own instance of that hierarchy.